# convert each word of sentence into string (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby

I have a string below

```
["Hindi, Tamil, Telugu, English, Kannada, Malayalam", "Telugu, Hindi, Tamil, Kannada, Malayalam"]
```

I want to make this as

```
["Hindi", "Tamil", "Telugu", "English", "Kannada", "Malayalam", "Telugu", "Hindi", "Tamil", "Kannada", "Malayalam"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given `a` your array

enough for your sample

```
a.flat_map { |w| w.split(', ') }
  => ["Hindi", "Tamil", "Telugu", "English", "Kannada", "Malayalam", "Telugu", "Hindi", "Tamil", "Kannada", "Malayalam"]
```

Something a little bit more tolerant/allowing

```
a.flat_map { |w| w.split(',') }.map(&:strip)
  => ["Hindi", "Tamil", "Telugu", "English", "Kannada", "Malayalam", "Telugu", "Hindi", "Tamil", "Kannada", "Malayalam"]
```

Comment: I'd do `a.flat_map { |w| w.split(",") }.map(&:strip)`. A little bit more tolerant/allowing.

Comment: applied Sergio, thanks

Comment: The call to map becomes unnecessary if you split using a regular expression that incorporates the whitespace. `a.flat_map { |w| w.split(/\s*,\s*/) }`

Comment: ...or `a.flat_map { |str| str.scan(/[^, ]+/) }`.